# How to specify 'os' for free gitlab runners ('runs-on' equivalent)

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, github, gitlab-ci-runner, workflow

How can I specify the operating system in the `.gitlab-ci` file to indicate which underlying OS on which the `gitlab-runner` should be running when using the [2,000 minutes of free execution](https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/) in with gitlab.com shared runners in Google Cloud Platform?

For context, Github's free account supports [2,000 free minutes](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-billing-and-payments-on-github/about-billing-for-github-actions) per month in "Github-hosted runners" for running [Github Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) in [Azure and MacStadium](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/virtual-environments-for-github-hosted-runners). You can specify whether you want the build to happen in Linux, Windows, or MacOS via the [`runs-on` key](https://help.github.com/en/actions/reference/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idruns-on) in the [github workflow yaml file](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows).

What is the equivalent method for specifying that I want to run a CI/CD job in a specific OS on GCP in the `.gitlab-ci` file?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify that you want gitlab to execute your CI job on a windows machine using [tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#tags).

Gitlab made Windows Shared Runners available as Beta in Jan 2020. [Their announcement](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/01/21/windows-shared-runner-beta/) shows how to use the `tags` key in your `.gitlab-ci` file to specify Windows machines.
You can also run in a docker container in windows:

- https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#using-windows-containers

For example, I was able to execute a simple "hello world" powershell script with the following job in [my `.gitlab-ci` file](https://gitlab.com/maltfield/cross-platform-python-gui/-/blob/91f0d9e31ed5c5cfdcd073accc1b3cc86a00df0b/.gitlab-ci.yml):

```yaml
windows:
  script: "build/windows/buildExe.ps1"
  tags:
    - shared-windows
    - windows
    - windows-1809
```

And here's the [`buildExe.ps1` powershell script](https://gitlab.com/maltfield/cross-platform-python-gui/-/blob/91f0d9e31ed5c5cfdcd073accc1b3cc86a00df0b/build/windows/buildExe.ps1) reference above:

```
Write-Host "listing contents of C drive root"
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ -Force

Write-Host "listing contents of cwd"
Get-ChildItem -Force
```

The above config produced the following output [in my CI job](https://gitlab.com/maltfield/cross-platform-python-gui/-/jobs/574193500):

```
[0KRunning with gitlab-runner 12.9.0 (4c96e5ad)
[0;m[0K  on windows-shared-runners-manager 6QgxEPvR
[0;msection_start:1590842482:prepare_executor
[0K[0K[36;1mPreparing the "custom" executor[0;m
[0;m[0KUsing Custom executor with driver autoscaler dev (64a348d)...
[0;mCreating virtual machine for the job...
Virtual machine created!
section_end:1590842624:prepare_executor
[0Ksection_start:1590842624:prepare_script
[0K[0K[36;1mPreparing environment[0;m
[0;mRunning on PACKER-5E557E8E via 
runner-6qgxepvr-wsrm-87cf700a3349de62a18e...
section_end:1590842640:prepare_script
[0Ksection_start:1590842640:get_sources
[0K[0K[36;1mGetting source from Git repository[0;m
[0;m[32;1mFetching changes with git depth set to 50...[0;m
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/GitLab-Runner/builds/maltfield/cross-platform-python-gui/.git/
[32;1mCreated fresh repository.[0;m
[32;1mChecking out 91f0d9e3 as master...[0;m
From https://gitlab.com/maltfield/cross-platform-python-gui
 * [new ref]         refs/pipelines/151176370 -> refs/pipelines/151176370
 * [new branch]      master                   -> origin/master
git-lfs/2.8.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.12.2; git 30af66bb)

[32;1mUpdating/initializing submodules...[0;m
git-lfs/2.8.0 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.12.2; git 30af66bb)
section_end:1590842661:get_sources
[0Ksection_start:1590842661:restore_cache
[0K[0K[36;1mRestoring cache[0;m
[0;msection_end:1590842670:restore_cache
[0Ksection_start:1590842670:download_artifacts
[0K[0K[36;1mDownloading artifacts[0;m
[0;msection_end:1590842677:download_artifacts
[0Ksection_start:1590842677:build_script
[0K[0K[36;1mRunning before_script and script[0;m
[0;m[32;1m$ build/windows/buildExe.ps1[0;m
listing contents of C drive root


    Directory: C:\


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
d--hs-       12/11/2019   2:47 AM                $RECYCLE.BIN                                                          
d--hs-        2/25/2020   8:52 PM                Boot                                                                  
d--hsl       12/11/2019  10:29 AM                Documents and Settings                                                
d-----        2/25/2020   8:16 PM                Git                                                                   
d-----        5/30/2020  12:44 PM                GitLab-Runner                                                         
d-----        2/25/2020   8:16 PM                GitLFS                                                                
d-----        2/25/2020   8:34 PM                Go                                                                    
d-----        9/15/2018   7:12 AM                PerfLogs                                                              
d-r---        2/25/2020   8:35 PM                Program Files                                                         
d-----        2/25/2020   8:27 PM                Program Files (x86)                                                   
d--h--        2/25/2020   8:51 PM                ProgramData                                                           
d--hs-        2/25/2020   8:10 PM                Recovery                                                              
d--hs-       12/11/2019  10:28 AM                System Volume Information                                             
d-----        2/25/2020   8:32 PM                tools                                                                 
d-r---        5/30/2020  12:43 PM                Users                                                                 
d-----        2/25/2020   8:38 PM                vcpkg                                                                 
d-----        2/25/2020   8:51 PM                Windows                                                               
-arhs-        2/25/2020   8:45 PM         408834 bootmgr                                                               
-a-hs-        9/15/2018   7:09 AM              1 BOOTNXT                                                               
-a-hs-        5/30/2020  12:41 PM     1073741824 pagefile.sys                                                          
listing contents of cwd


    Directory: C:\GitLab-Runner\builds\maltfield\cross-platform-python-gui


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                                                                  
----                -------------         ------ ----                                                                  
d--h--        5/30/2020  12:44 PM                .git                                                                  
d-----        5/30/2020  12:44 PM                build                                                                 
d-----        5/30/2020  12:44 PM                src                                                                   
-a----        5/30/2020  12:44 PM            534 .gitlab-ci.yml                                                        
-a----        5/30/2020  12:44 PM          35787 LICENSE                                                               
-a----        5/30/2020  12:44 PM           1171 README.md                                                             
-a----        5/30/2020  12:44 PM              6 requirements.txt                                                      


section_end:1590842686:build_script
[0Ksection_start:1590842686:archive_cache
[0K[0K[36;1mSaving cache[0;m
[0;msection_end:1590842694:archive_cache
[0Ksection_start:1590842694:upload_artifacts_on_success
[0K[0K[36;1mUploading artifacts for successful job[0;m
[0;msection_end:1590842701:upload_artifacts_on_success
[0K[32;1mJob succeeded
[0;m
```

As for MacOS, gitlab currently doesn't support it natively.
If this changes, updated answers are welcome.

Other answers showing how to run MacOS inside a VM (eg using vagrant and libvirt) on a gitlab shared runner are very welcome :)